# Javascript highlight all excluded characters with a color

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, preg-replace

I would like to create a regex in Javascript that highlights all excluded characters from a list with a `<span></span>`. Could someone help me with creating this complicated regex?

Example text: `This is a text 莊子 that contains · forbidden characters.`

Need to be converted to: `This is a text <span>莊</span><span>子</span> that contains <span>·</span> forbidden characters.`

The list of allowed characters: `a-z, A-Z, 0-9, +%#()*+,-/:;<=>?_€£¥§ÄÅÜäèéìñòöùü=“”‘’'"`

Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use negated pattern:

```
str = str.replace(/[^ \w+%#()*+.,/:;<=>?€£¥§ÄÅÜäèéìñòöùü=“”‘’'"-]/g, '<span>$&</span>');

//=> This is a text <span>莊</span><span>子</span> that contains <span>·</span> forbidden characters.
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dX9oN7/1)